# Angular template not rendering value of property, but | json on the same object shows property has value

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an Observable object that I'm selecting out of my store in an angular component. The template looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
  {{ user | json }}
  <h1>Welcome, {{ user.email }}!</h1>
  <button (click)="onLogout()">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Where the template renders the object as a json string, I can see there is a property called "email" with a value. I know that the Observable stream has a value, because the *ngIf is evaluating truthy. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: what is the exact value displayed by the `| json` ?

Comment: { "_delegate": { "uid": "4KEvp9jo6XY3Kc1kt776CBHrWsg2", "email": "test@hotmail.com", "emailVerified": false, "isAnonymous": false, ...

Comment: Doh! I just realized the issue. I didn't see it was a sub property of _delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the `json` output, your email is nested into a `_delegate` object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo - unnecessary "("

```
{{ (user.email }}
---^
```

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo in my post. Not the issue.